# Combine two strings with for loop

Tags: php

Is it possible to combine two strings with for loop?
For example:

```
echo 'Prefix '.for($i=0;$i<4;$i++){ echo $i; }.' suffix';
```

This is not possible:

```
echo 'Prefix ';
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
   echo $i;
}
echo ' suffix';
```

Because I would like to save a page using `file_put_contents` and source has a combination of HTML and PHP.

I would like to get:

```
$page =    <beginning_of_html_page_here>
    <php_code_here>
    <end_html_page_here>

file_put_contents(page.html, $page);
```

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to print numbers or save a file?

Comment: Maybe you could use an [output buffer](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php)?

Comment: May be you want: `echo 'sufix' . $i . 'prefix'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [string concatenation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.string.php). Use the dot `.` to join to strings, `'a'.'b'` will give `'ab'`. And `$a .= 'c'` will append `'c'` to the `$a` variable.

```
// Create the string
$string = 'Prefix ';
for($i=0;$i<4;$i++)
{
   // Append the numbers to the string
   $string .= $i;
}
// Append the suffix to the string
$string .= ' suffix';
// Display the string
echo $string;
```

Result is:

> Prefix 0123 suffix

[Demo at Codepad](http://codepad.org/KCV689NQ).

---

About the end of your question, you can use this logic:

```
$page = '<beginning_of_html_page_here>';

// Append things to your string with PHP
$page .= 'something'

$page .= '<end_html_page_here>';
```

---

About your first code block, this can also be done by using two functions: [`range()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.range.php) to generate an array of numbers and [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) to join the array's items:

```
<?php

// Create the string
$string = 'Prefix '.implode('', range(0, 3)).' suffix';
echo $string;
```